# Seeking shapefile of Boston in 1630?

Tags: geospatial, usa

I found this map on Reddit and was curious if anyone knows how it was made.

See [Modern map of Boston compared to original 1630 shoreline](https://www.reddit.com/r/boston/comments/2xu9ix/modern_map_of_boston_compared_to_original_1630/).

I think I could make it if I had a shapefile of the 1630 map.

Does anyone know how I could get that?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Cool question and nice map...*

I did a reverse image search and found a [blog post from 2011](http://marybarrettdyer.blogspot.com/2011/11/), the same year as the map's creation, which has lots of technical details:

https://www.digitalcommonwealth.org/search/commonwealth:7h149v32x

```
Title:
    1630 shoreline 
Creator:
    Metropolitan Planning Organization (Mass.). Central Transportation Planning Staff. 
Name on Item:
    Central Transportation Planning Staff.
Date:
    2011
Format:
    Maps/Atlases
Location:
    Boston Public Library
    Norman B. Leventhal Map Center 
Collection (local):
    Norman B. Leventhal Map Center Collection
Subjects:
    Local transit--Massachusetts--Boston--Maps
    Fills (Earthwork)--Massachusetts--Boston--History--Maps
    Boston (Mass.)--History--Maps
Places:
    Massachusetts > Suffolk (county) > Boston
Extent:
    1 map : col., mounted on foamboard ; 78 x 62 cm. 
Permalink:
    https://ark.digitalcommonwealth.org/ark:/50959/7h149v32x 
Terms of Use:
    No known copyright restrictions.
    No known restrictions on use.
```

Also has a 74 MB [GeoTIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoTIFF) download in the right menu bar

[image]

GeoTIFF seems to be a useable format for converting to shapefiles or other GIS formats:

- [direct GeoTIFF download](https://www.digitalcommonwealth.org/downloads/commonwealth:7h149v336?datastream_id=georectifiedMaster)
- [GDAL GeoTIFF docs](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html)
- [Blogpost about displaying GeoTIFF in QGIS](https://support.dronedeploy.com/docs/displaying-elevation-data-in-qgis)

Comment: for questions about GeoTIFF conversion, and if you can't find existing answers/resources, please ask on https://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: wow, thatnks for the great answer!

Answer (score 2):

You asked for a **shapefile** of the Boston harbor shoreline for 1630. However, what seems to be available from that era is mostly raster images of maps. So you will probably need to digitize the shoreline yourself from a georeferenced image. In addition to the original map (provided in philshem's answer), there are many different sources of historical maps.

---

NOAA (National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration, U.S. Department of Commerce)
provides a [Historical Shoreline Survey Viewer](https://shoreline.noaa.gov/data/datasheets/t-sheets.html). If you open this tool in Google Earth, it assists you to download historical shorelines for various dates, going back as far as 1841.

> The NOAA Historical Shoreline Survey Viewer provides access to a large number of historical shoreline surveys conducted by NOAA and its predecessor organizations. About 7,800 surveys—the earliest dating back to 1841—are available for viewing in Google Earth. In addition to overlaying a scanned image of the survey in Google Earth, the viewer provides links to download: the original scan and metadata, the resulting extracted vector shoreline, and a descriptive report compiled by the survey team.

---

Historical, georeferenced nautical maps are available at [historicalcharts.noaa.gov](https://historicalcharts.noaa.gov). There are three maps of Boston Harbor between 1600 and 1800:

[image]

- [BOSTON ITS ENVIRONS & HARBOUR WITH THE REBEL WORKS](https://historicalcharts.noaa.gov/image=844-00-1775), Nautical Chart, 1775
- [[Nachant Bay and Boston Harbour]](https://historicalcharts.noaa.gov/image=BOSHAR), Nautical Chart, 1781
- [A NEW PLAN OF BOSTON HARBOR](https://historicalcharts.noaa.gov/image=844-00-1774), City Plan, 1774

---

The Norman B. Leventhal Map & Education Center at the Boston Public Library has a digital archive of historical maps. Some of them are georeferenced already. Others are waiting to be georeferenced.

- [Link](https://collections.leventhalmap.org/search?f%5Bsubject_facet_ssim%5D%5B%5D=Boston%20Harbor%20%28Mass.%29--Maps--Early%20works%20to%201800&per_page=100&q=boston%20harbor&search_field=all_fields) - many historical maps of Boston Harbor
- [Link](https://collections.leventhalmap.org/search?f%5Bname_facet_ssim%5D%5B%5D=Map%20Works%2C%20Inc.) - simple, modern maps of the Boston Harbor shoreline at different dates from 1630 to 1995. It would probably be pretty easy to digitize the shoreline from these maps. This series of maps was made by [Map Works, Inc](https://www.mapworksinc.com/). They obviously have a vector layer of the 1630 Boston Harbor shoreline, but they don't provide it on their website. As a private company they have no obligation to provide their source data, but you could certainly contact them and request it.

---

The NYU Spatial Data Repository has this georeferenced map, [Boston proper, Massachusetts, 1895, showing historic shorelines (Raster Image)](https://geo.nyu.edu/catalog/harvard-matwn-3764-b6-1895-p4). I believe the "original shoreline" mentioned in the description is the 1630 shoreline.

> This map shows Boston proper's original shoreline and changes in wharf line for years 1795, 1850 and 1895.

---

NOAA provides high-resolution historical and modern vector shorelines as shapefiles [here](https://shoreline.noaa.gov/data/datasheets/usgs.html). Description:

> The U.S. Geological Survey (USGS) produced a comprehensive database of digital vector shorelines by compiling shoreline positions from pre-existing historical shoreline databases and by generating historical and modern shoreline data. Shorelines are compiled by state and generally correspond to one of four periods: 1800s, 1920s-1930s, 1970s, and 1998-2002. Each shoreline may represent a compilation of data from one or more sources for one or more dates provided by one or more agencies.

- Preview the shorelines [here](https://coastalmap.marine.usgs.gov/js_map/national/ShoreLC/)
- All data downloads for the [US Mid-Atlantic and New England here](http://pubs.usgs.gov/of/2010/1119/data_catalog.html).
- Direct download link for [GreaterBoston_shorelines.zip](https://pubs.usgs.gov/of/2010/1119/data/GreaterBoston_shorelines.zip), which includes shapefiles of shorelines for the Greater Boston area from 1847 to 2000.

---

Other old maps of Boston can be found on [Oldmapsonline.org](https://www.oldmapsonline.org/en/Boston).